# IOS How to retain data?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have a app, where I've a tabview controller. All the data is dynamic, and when I enter on one tab, the data is loaded, but if I change my tab and come back to the initial tab, I haven't lost the data on it, what is awesome. My problem now is that I've built a new viewcontroller (outside the tabs) and when I go into it, and come back to the tabs I've lost all my information!

Is there any way to retain the initial data? So there when the user goes to that another view, and comes back, don't have to lose the data.

And another question. Is there anyway, to define variables that are available to every viewcontroller's in the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data will not change when you move from one tab to the other
You will need to check if you have some special code in your `viewWillAppear`, if you load the data in this function you should know that viewWillAppear gets called when you travel tabs

About the global Data, you could define them in your appDelegate class, add properties to the appDelegate and then you can access them like this

```
//Add this on the header of your class
#import "MyAppDelegate.h"

//Then access the delegate like this
MyAppDelegate *myAppDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
//Access your variables
myAppDelegate.myVariables;
```

Comment: Yes the data dont't change when i move from one tab to another, but whet i get out of the tabs, to a separated viewcontroller, and i came back, I lose all that data :S

To be more specific, I have a tab where i have some thumps of photos, and i want to do a view with fullscreen for that photos. And when i came back form fullscreen, i want to have all the inf that i had before.

Comment: your viewcontroller has been most deallocated, you will have to save all the data you want to a file on your device and then load it later

Answer (score 1):

What is this general data? If it is objects, I would call retain. But if it was a data type, try making is static and make a method returning it. Or you could wrap it in an object, (like NSNumber for example if it was a float, double or int etc.) then call retain to that.